# Create function that returns a "SELECT" statement result

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-function

I was told to create a mysql function that, given the artwork title, return the name of the creator. I know it sounds silly, i could use just a select.

I followed some tutorials, but none of them helped me. When I try to create the function, mysql workbench says "Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a function"

Here is what i'm trying to do

```
delimiter $$
    create function findObject(workName VARCHAR(45)) returns VARCHAR(250)
    begin
    SELECT result= ar.artistName FROM artist as ar, art_object as oa
            where ar.artistCode= oa.artistCode
            and oa.title= workName 
            group by ar.artistName ;
    return result;
    end$$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not how you assign the result of a variable in a `SELECT` statement. You have to use `SELECT ... INTO variable`.

You also need to declare the variable first.

```
delimiter $$
create function findObject(workName VARCHAR(45)) returns VARCHAR(250)
begin
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(250);
    SELECT DISTINCT ar.artistName FROM artist as ar, art_object as oa
    INTO result
    where ar.artistCode= oa.artistCode
    and oa.title= workName;
    return result;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

`SELECT result = ar.artistName` is comparing the value of `result` with `ar.artistName`, and returning the result of that comparison from the `SELECT` statement.